# Modify Call using AMD in Twilio

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-amd

How to modify Call using AMD in Twilio

Till Now i have done this

```
var call = CallResource.Create(
                machineDetection: "Enable",
                url:  new Uri("https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHef.."),
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(to),
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(callerId),
                pathAccountSid: accountSid
           );
```

what i want if call is answered by human 
than caller and client should connect
esle
an recorded file should play to an answering machine

my twiml bin

```
<Response>
   {{#AnsweredBy}}
    <Dial>
      <Number>
        {{to}}
      </Number> 
    </Dial>
   {{/AnsweredBy}}
   {{^AnsweredBy}}
      <Play>{{recordFile}}</Play>
   {{/AnsweredBy}}
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You won't be able to react to the `AnsweredBy` parameter in a TwiML Bin. When using [AMD](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection) the [`AnsweredBy` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#webhook-parameters) will always have a value, one of `machine_start`, `human`, `fax` or `unknown` when using `Enable`.

You'll need to build a dynamic endpoint that checks against those values and responds with the TwiML you want to play for each potential result.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thank you @philnash, I am using callbackevent to modify call now

Comment: @SimarjeetSinghPanghlia Could you please elaborate? did you use it with AMD? or as an alternative?